# C# Sum values in a List with multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, sum

Was following tutorial here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/chash-linq-sum-method to Sum up values in a list. But I have multiple columns so code fails at:

```
            double res = ProductList.AsQueryable().Sum();
            Console.WriteLine(res);
```

see end of the file here https://dotnetfiddle.net/vmtTuP for issue.

Comment: `double res = ProductList.Sum(item => item.Qty);` you should specify the value (property, column etc.) which you want to sum.

Comment: Looks like `Tax` because `res` is a `double`.

Comment: Updated https://dotnetfiddle.net/vmtTuP adds the number of entries but not the sum?

Comment: While Dotnet Fiddle is a great tool to let someone run c# code online, please add your [mre] here, in the post itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `AsQueryable()` and all you need to do is specify the field of your object you wish to sum - for example if you wanted to sum `Tax`:

```
double res = ProductList.Sum(x => x.Tax);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

In a simple case, if you want to `Sum` some value, say, `Qty`, just specify it:

```
  double res = ProductList.Sum(item => item.Qty);
```

If you want to sum *several* values (say, *both* `Qty` and `Tax`) in *one go* you can use `Aggregate`:

```
  (double Qty, double Tax) res = ProductList
    .Aggregate((Qty : 0.0, Tax : 0.0), (s, a) => (s.Qty + a.Qty, s.Tax + a.Tax)); 

  Console.Write($"Qty = {res.Qty}; Tax = {res.Tax}");
```